# Excel Conditional Formatting of Dates Automatically

Tags: excel, date, conditional-formatting

Is there a way for Conditional Formatting in Excel to refer to a whole column from the original reference column?

For example, i want the E column to refer to the C column such that if the dates in the E column are 2 days after the dates in the E column, it will turn green. And i want to be able to do this as fast as possible.

The problem is that right now even if the function would just be the same for the E to C column at each row, i have to do it one by one. Is there anyway to match the whole E column to the C column?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called auto fill in Excel. The auto fill function makes it possible to automatically fill in your function in a whole column with just a few clicks.

[image][link to tutorial](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel101/ss/freeze_pane_3.htm)

Example of auto fill:

1. Enter 1 in cell A1
2. Write =(A1+1) in cell A2
3. Select cell range A2:A10
4. Click on "Fill" in the ribbon (see image)
5. Select Down
6. Now there is numbers 1-10 in columns A1:A10

You may use this feature to add cells with your function in a whole column.

Comment: im sorry but it isnt auto-complete that i was looking for. i need something for conditional formatting.

for example:

COLUMN A | COLUMN B
21-Oct     23-Oct

So if the value in column b is greater than column a itll turn green. 
I can do this per row, one column to another column but not the WHOLE column to column to their corresponding row.

Comment: I do not mean the auto complete feature. I edidted my answer and added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional format on the first cell in the column, and use the format painter to copy it to the rest of the column. Use a formula like '=B1=A1+2' as condition for the first cell. Make sure there are no dollarsigns in the formula!

Alternatively, you could use manage rules to apply them to a range. Have a look at the pictures below. I cannot post them here because I have not enough credits yet :-)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA3o9.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYcvQ.jpg

Comment: Hi! I tried the solution however, it its only limited to a single point of reference. What im looking for is that as the target changes, the reerence changes as well. 

So for example, when B1 is equal to A1 by date, it changes color. But for B2 i need it to reference to A2, B3 to A3, etc. :)

Would you happen to know how?